# JSON (org.json) looses values when send it to REST service

Tags: java, json, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey

I'm practice with REST services. I'm trying to send an JSON (JSONObject from org.json library) but when i try to read the JSON in the REST method, it is empty. I print the length of the JSON sended and displays '0'.

**REST service**

```
@Path("/users")
public class UserService {   
    final private UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
    final private UserEmailDao userEmailDao = new UserEmailDao();
    final private UserPhoneDao userPhoneDao = new UserPhoneDao();

    @POST
    @Path("/save")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public void save(JSONObject user) {
        System.out.println(user.length()); // prints '0'
    }
    @PUT
    @Path("/update")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public void update(JSONObject user) {

    }
    @DELETE
    @Path("/remove/{id}")
    public void delete(@PathParam("id") Short id) {

    }
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    @Path("/all")
    public String findAll() {
        System.out.println("Recuperar todos!");
        return "<p>Accediendo a todos los usuarios...</p>";
    }
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/find/{i}")
    public void find(@PathParam("id") Short id) {

    }

}
```

**Client**

```
public class ClientTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ClientTest.class.getName());
        try {
            Map<String, List<?>> user = new HashMap<>();
            List<Object> userData = new ArrayList<>();
            Collections.addAll(userData,
                    "Shaquille", "O'neil", "12345678", "06-03-1972",
                    "Av. desconocida #123", "28/03/2015", (Boolean) true);
            user.put("user", userData);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("user", user);
            System.out.println(json.length()); // prints '1'
            Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
            WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/UsersControl/api/users/save");
            Response response = target.request()
                    .buildPost(Entity.entity(json, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).invoke();
            System.out.println(response);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            logger.warning(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Why happen this? I'm doing something wrong? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The error might be in your client code. Have you tried using postman or equivalent to test the rest service with a json string to make sure it works?

Using jersey and Jackson makes this all quite easy.

Also the path annotation on your last get method is {i} but should be {id}

**UPDATE**

Since I originally did not give a complete answer with code, here is my complete answer. The problem I believe is with using the JSONObject as opposed to using a defined class that can be serialized by the ObjectMapper. Here is an example of working code using Jersey/Jackson (maven project)

First, setup files

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.vbranden</groupId>
    <artifactId>UserWS</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>UserRESTWS</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>User REST WS</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>com.vbranden.UserWSApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>User REST WS</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**UserWSApplication.java**

```
package com.vbranden;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

public class UserWSApplication extends Application {
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        s.add(UserService.class);
        return s;
    }
}
```

Now I will define a UserModel class that can be serialized by the ObjectMapper

**UserModel.java**

```
package com.vbranden;

import java.util.List;

public class UserModel {

    private String username;
    private List<Object> userData;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public List<Object> getUserData() {
        return userData;
    }
    public void setUserData(List<Object> userData) {
        this.userData = userData;
    }
}
```

Now I will create the web service and add a resource called /testsave to test the ClientTest object (seems funny but the point is to test the client code)

**UserService.java**

```
package com.vbranden;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.json.JSONObject;

@Path("/users")
public class UserService {   
    /*
    final private UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
    final private UserEmailDao userEmailDao = new UserEmailDao();
    final private UserPhoneDao userPhoneDao = new UserPhoneDao();
    */

    @POST
    @Path("/save")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response save(UserModel user) {
        return Response.ok().entity(user).build();
    }
    @PUT
    @Path("/update")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public void update(UserModel user) {

    }
    @DELETE
    @Path("/remove/{id}")
    public void delete(@PathParam("id") Short id) {

    }
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    @Path("/all")
    public String findAll() {
        System.out.println("Recuperar todos!");
        return "<p>Accediendo a todos los usuarios...</p>";
    }
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/find/{id}")
    public void find(@PathParam("id") Short id) {

    }

    @GET
    @Path("/testsave")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response testSave() {
        ClientTest clientTest = new ClientTest();
        return clientTest.test();
    }
}
```

and finally the updated client code using the UserModel class instead of JSONObject

**ClientTest.java**

```
package com.vbranden;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class ClientTest {
    public ClientTest() { }

    public Response test() {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ClientTest.class.getName());
        try {


            UserModel user = new UserModel();
            user.setUsername("shaqattack");

            List<Object> userData = new ArrayList<Object>();
            Collections.addAll(userData, "Shaquille", "O'neil", "12345678", "06-03-1972",
                    "Av. desconocida #123", "28/03/2015", (Boolean) true);
            user.setUserData(userData);

            Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
            WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/StackOverflow-29332634/users/save");
            Response response = target.request()
                    .buildPost(Entity.entity(user, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).invoke();
            System.out.println(response);
            return response;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            logger.warning(e.getMessage());
            return Response.status(404).build();
        }
    }
}
```

then using postman to test the rest client

[image]

Comment: For now, i just send the JSON as String and in the REST method transform this String to JSON and get the values for set the User's properties. Thanks for your suggestion man.

Comment: sorry immibis, i have updated my answer accordingly.